# Cause linter to warn on usage of specific symbol in external library

Tags: python, pylint, flake8

How can I configure pylint and/or flake8 to show a warning/error on a specific import from a specific module of an external package.

For context: I have a Django project that requires a custom implementation for `login_required`. It would be good to have a linter warning for developers who forgot to use the custom implementation and use the default one of Django to avoid subtle errors.

I prefer to have the explicit import and not use monkey patching.

Comment: requesting suggestions for tools and libraries is off topic for stack overflow as it tends to invite spammy results -- for instance as the flake8 maintainer I'd probably suggest you write a custom flake8 plugin but you really could solve this in many other ways or with other tools and libraries

Comment: The question does not solicit suggestions for tools or libraries. Nor is that an implication of the question.

Comment: what have you tried then?

Answer (score 1):

First `pip install pylint-forbidden-imports`, then you can do `pylint my_cool_project --load-plugins=pylint_forbidden_imports` or append it to your pylintrc file:

```
[MASTER]
load-plugins=pylint_forbidden_imports
```

See https://pypi.org/project/pylint-forbidden-imports/ for configuration